# how can I use array's inside object data in an another new array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const oldArray = [
    {
        names: ["all", "breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"],
        length: [346, 24, 6, 99]
    }
]
```

transform this into a new array using JavaScript. The new array result should look like this:

```
const newArray = ["all (346)", "breakfast (24)", "lunch (6)", "dinner (99)"]
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```js
const oldArray = [
    {
        names: ["all", "breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"],
        length: [346, 24, 6, 99]
    }
];

const newArray = oldArray[0].names.map((name, index) => `${name} (${oldArray[0].length[index]})`);

console.log(newArray);
```